# how to run multiple queries using psycopg AsyncConnectionPool

Tags: python, python-asyncio, psycopg3

I would like to run 5 queries asynchronously using the psycopg_pool. I am not entirely familiar with asyncio and running into an issue. I am hoping someone would be helpful in explaining and debuging my code below as I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
import psycopg
import psycopg_pool
from psycopg.rows import dict_row

class AsyncDBPool:
    def __init__(self, pool_size:int):
        self.pool = psycopg_pool.AsyncConnectionPool(
            conninfo="host={} port={} dbname={} user={} password={}" \
                .format(HOSTNAME, PORT, DBNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD),
            min_size= 1,
            max_size= pool_size,
            timeout=30,
            open=False
        )
    
    async def open_pool(self):
        await self.pool.open()
        await self.pool.wait()

    async def execute(self, query:str, args:tuple=()):
        async with self.pool.connection() as conn:
            async with conn.cursor(row_factory=dict_row) as cur:
                await cur.execute(query, args)
                await conn.commit()
    
    async def execute_all(self, queries:list):
        assert isinstance(queries, list), "must be list"
        asyncio.gather(*(self.execute(qa['query'], qa['args']) for qa in queries), return_exceptions=True)

        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    queries = [
        {
            "query": "insert into test (entry) values (%s);", 
            "args": n 
        } for n in range(10)
    ]
    asyncio.run(AsyncDBPool(5).execute_all(queries))
```

I am not getting any errors but the queries are not committing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I was able to figure it out, I did not open the pool within the execute_all function and did not await the gathering of tasks. If someone could explain why it didn't work for first time, that would be great :)

Below is the working code:

```
class AsyncDBPool:
    def __init__(self, min_conn:int):
        self.pool = psycopg_pool.AsyncConnectionPool(
            conninfo="host={} port={} dbname={} user={} password={}" \
                .format(POSTGRES_HOSTNAME, POSTGRES_PORT, POSTGRES_DBNAME, POSTGRES_USERNAME, POSTGRES_PASSWORD),
            min_size= 5,
            max_size= MAX_POOL_SIZE,
            timeout=30,
            max_idle= 300,
            open=False
        )
    
    async def open_pool(self):
        await self.pool.open()
        await self.pool.wait()
        print("Connection to database established")

    async def execute(self, query:str, args:tuple=()):
        async with self.pool.connection() as conn:
            async with conn.cursor(row_factory=dict_row) as cur:
                await cur.execute(query, (args,))
                await conn.commit()

    async def execute_all(self, queries:list):
        #validation
        assert isinstance(queries, list), "queries must be a list"
        assert len(queries), "queries cannot be empty"
        assert all(isinstance(q, dict) for q in queries), "queries must contain dict type values"
        assert all("query" in q and "args" in q for q in queries), "queries objects must contain 'query' and 'args'"

        # open pool, gather/execute tasks, close pool
        await self.open_pool()
        await asyncio.gather(*(self.execute(q['query'], q['args']) for q in queries), return_exceptions=True)
        await self.pool.close()
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    queries = [
        {
            "query": "insert into test (entry) values (%s);", 
            "args": n
        } for n in range(10)
    ]
    asyncio.run(AsyncDBPool(5).execute_all(queries))
```